# Json ClassCastException cannot cast Object to mjson.Json

Tags: java

Please keep in mind I am new to netbeans and java. It is compiling but on run getting the above error .

> Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to mjson.Json

error throw at me is

```
package javaapplication1;

import mjson.Json;


public class JavaApplication1 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    String jsonStr = 
            "{" +
            "\"firstName\":\"John\"," +
            "\"lastName\": \"Smith\"," +
            "\"isAlive\": true," +
            "\"age\": 25,"+
            "\"address\":" +
            "{"+
            "\"streetAddress\": \"21 2nd Street\","+
            "\"city\": \"New York\"," +
            "\"state\" \"NY\"," +
            "\"postalCode\": \"10021-3100\"" +
            "}," +
            "\"phoneNumbers\":"+
            "[" +
            "{" +
            "\"type\": \"home\"," +
            "\"number\": \"212 555-1234\"" +
            "},"+
            "{" +
            "\"type\":\"office\"," +
            "\"number\" : \"646 555-4567\"" +
            "}" +
            "]," +
            "\"children\" : [],"+
            "\"spouse\" : null" +
            "}";
      Json json =Json.read(jsonStr);

    System.out.print(jsonStr);

 }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: `"\"state\" \"NY\","` this line is wrong. Changes to `"\"state\": \"NY\","`